# When using an expression, is there a way to... not replace the previous value?

Tags: angularjs

I know that by doing

```
{{bubba}}
```

Will output the bubba value in the current scope, but can I have the expression not... do anything (not update the DOM) based on a value? Essentially, what i'm trying to accomplish is if the value is false, show the previous value.

```
{{!bubba ? dontDisplayEvalutedExpression : bubba}}
```

Adding a plunker as an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yYy62x2aK2RiDCUxwtAK

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: Basically, if the value evaluates to false, display the previous value. Figure if the expression can handle this, it'll be easier than keeping track in the controller.

Comment: can you provide fiddle with your desired scenery ? @Charlie

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way,

```
  {{bubba === "one" ? "it's true" : "it's false"}}
```

Working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/EecdhaSnGGhvrOA0pk8V?p=preview)

Else if you want to generate new dom elements you can use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

Comment: This won't do exactly what I need. I want to display bubba's value and if its false, display its previous value.

Comment: if you have two variables to store the current value and previous value,then can accomplish